# Can I compile boost.python module without bjam?

Tags: python, c++, boost

Boost.python module provides a easy way of blinding c/c++ codes into Python. However, most tutorials assume that bjam is used to compile this module. I was wondering if I do not compile this module can I still use this module? What I mean "do not compile this module" is  including all the source files of Boost.python in my current project. I did it for other modules from Boost. For example, the Boost.filesystem module, when I use this module, I just include all the files from this module and compile them with the codes I have written. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, it's just a library, link with it and there you go (you may need to link with python lib as well, don't recall of the top of my head). I guess I'm lazy, so I've never even bothered using bjam for anything else than building boost itself. TBH the official tutorial is rather unfortunate, since i constantly see people here struggling with boost.python usually since they believe that they have to use bjam (and fail in doing so).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely, it's a library like any other.

I always use it with CMake, but anything will do. You need to

- Add to include paths the location of the boost headers.
- Add to include paths the location of python headers (usually installed with Python, location depends on OS)
- Link with the appropriate boost.python library (e.g. in my case it's `boost_python-vc120-mt-1_58.lib` or `boost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib`, again depends on version/os/toolkit)